# How to use custom Validator in Angular5 and spring-boot

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, angular5

I'm working with a simple angular5 app in front end , using HTTPCLIENT , and spring-boot in back-end , i'm creating a simple component to add a new client,with field username .

i'm trying to use custum validator so i can check if the username is unique or already used , but i'm fascing many errors .
This is Angular side

new-client.component.html

```
<div >
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <strong>add a new client</strong>
      </div>

      <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="SaveClient()">

      <div class="card-body">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="vat">Email </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vat"   formControlName="username" />
          <div class="error" *ngIf="form.controls['username'].invalid && form.controls['username'].errors.required && (form.controls['username'].dirty || form.controls['username'].touched)">Please enter an email</div>
          <div class="error" *ngIf="form.controls['username'].invalid && form.controls['username'].errors.email && (form.controls['username'].dirty || form.controls['username'].touched)">Please enter a valid email</div>
          <div class="error" *ngIf="form.controls['username'].invalid && form.controls['username'].errors.emailTaken">This email has been taken, please use another one.</div>
        </div>
        <div formGroupName = "passwordG">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="vat">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="vat"    formControlName="password" />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="vat">Confirmation Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="vat" formControlName="Confirmationpassword" />
          </div>


          <div *ngIf="(form.controls['passwordG'].invalid && form.controls['passwordG'].touched)" class="col-sm-3 text-danger">

            <ng-container *ngIf="form.controls['passwordG'].errors?.mismatch;
                then first else second"> </ng-container>

            <ng-template #first>
              Password do not match </ng-template>

            <ng-template #second>
              Password needs to be more than 8 characters
            </ng-template>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i>Enregistrer</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div><!--/.col-->
</div>
```

new-client.component.ts

```
function passwordMatch(control: AbstractControl):{[key: string]: boolean}{

  const password = control.get('password');
  const Confirmationpassword = control.get('Confirmationpassword');

  if( !password || !Confirmationpassword) {
    return null; }

  if(password.value === Confirmationpassword.value){
    return null;
  }

  return {
    mismatch:true
  }

}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-clients',
  templateUrl: './new-clients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-clients.component.scss']
})
export class NewClientsComponent implements OnInit {

  client:Clients = new Clients();
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private clientService:ClientService,
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              public router:Router,
              public activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({

      username: ['', Validators.required , Validators.email  , this.validateEmailNotTaken.bind(this)],
      passwordG: this.formBuilder.group({
        password: ['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(9)]],
        Confirmationpassword : ['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(9)]]

      }, {validator: passwordMatch})

    });
  }

  SaveClient(){

    this.client.setUsername(this.form.value.username);
    this.client.setPassword(this.form.value.passwordG.password);

    this.clientService.saveClient(this.client)
      .subscribe((data:Clients)=>{
        swal("operation réussi !", "great !", "success");
        this.router.navigate([ '../list' ], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });
      },err=>{
        console.log(err);
      })

  }

  validateEmailNotTaken(control: AbstractControl) {
    return this.clientService.checkEmailNotTaken(control.value).map(res => {
      return res ? null : { emailTaken: true };
    }); //somthing is wrong HERE ! 
  }


}
```

client.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ClientService {
checkEmailNotTaken(email:string){
    if(this.authService.getToken()==null) {
      this.authService.loadToken();
    }
    return this.http.post(this.host+
      "/checkEmailUnique/",{email},{headers:new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':this.authService.getToken()})});
  }


}
```

In spring-boot :

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/checkEmailUnique",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public EmailStatusCheckJson checkEmailUnique(@RequestBody final AppUser appUser){

        final EmailStatusCheckJson returnValue = new EmailStatusCheckJson();

              System.out.println("username **"+appUser.getUsername());
         AppUser app = userRepo.findByUsername(appUser.getUsername());


         if(app!=null){
             System.out.println("exists");
             returnValue.setEmailIsAvailable(false);
         }
         else{
             System.out.println("doesnt exist ");
             returnValue.setEmailIsAvailable(true);

         }

         return returnValue;
    }
```

This is the error i'm getting

```
ERROR Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.
    at toObservable (forms.js:749)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at FormControl.eval [as asyncValidator] (forms.js:729)
    at FormControl.AbstractControl._runAsyncValidator (forms.js:3447)
    at FormControl.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:3390)
    at FormControl.setValue (forms.js:3973)
```

Any idea ? I'm new to angular .

Comment: Its either Angular or Spring. Both are separate applications. Sio you ask for validator on backend or frontend?

Comment: I'm asking for validator in front end in angular side , i just added all the code so it seems clear .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is expacted for a control is

- the value of the control, then
- a validator or an array of validators, then
- an async validator or an array of async validators

So it should be

```
['', [Validators.required, Validators.email], this.validateEmailNotTaken.bind(this)]
```

since the `validateEmailNotTaken` is an async validator.

Comment: I dont get any error now , the Validators.required, Validators.email are working , but this.validateEmailNotTaken.bind(this) seems not to work as it doesnt tell me that username is already in use . i've already tested the rest controller with ARC client and it works well .

Comment: That's because your validator is incorrect: it returns null if you get a non-null body as a response from your post request. And your server controller always returns a non-null body.

Comment: Ah i see , how can i then test and return true or false then?

Comment: You're not supposed to return true or false. You're supposed to return null if there is no error, or `{ emailTaken: true }` if there is one. The server returns `{ emailIsAvailable: false }` when the email is taken, and `{ emailIsAvailable: true }` when it's not taken. This shouldn't be too hard to figure out.

Comment: You're right , but i think i'm missing something another time , i have edited the post if you can please take a look a it again . , i'm always getting email already used , choose another one , even the emails that are not in database.

Comment: You should be able to debug this by yourself. Why don't you open your browser dev tools and look at what you receive? The server is now sending null when when the email is available. And in that case, your validator returns an error, which is the inverse of what it should do. When the email is not available, the server now returns `{ emailIsAvailable: true }`, which is extremely confusing since the email is NOT available, and emailIsAvailable should thus NOT be true. In short, the whole logic is backwards.

Comment: Your server code was correct before. What was wrong was your validator. And you chose to introduce bugs on the server instead of fixing the validator.

Comment: I'm so sorry for that i'm not able now to figure out what i'm doing , i'll try a little bit to understand and then try some solutions,I appreciate your help .

Comment: Let's go back to your previous server code. If it returns `{ emailIsAvailable: true }`, that means "no error", and your validator must thus return null. If it returns `{ emailIsAvailable: false }`, that means an error, and your validator must return `{ emailTaken: true }`. This is quite simple logic. All you need is `return res.emailIsAvailable ? null : { emailTaken: true }`. Or, if you don't get the ternary operator: `if (res.emailIsAvailable) { return null; } else { return { emailTaken: true }; }`

Comment: This seems logic to me now , but res.emailIsAvailable is unknow here , im not sur how it will be known by the compilator .

Comment: By defining an interface describing the structure of the response sent by the server (let's call it EmailAvailability), and then using `http.post<EmailAvailability>`. Or by using `any`, but that is ugly and not safe.

Comment: Thank you so much for being this much helpful , i could understand how this was working and fixed the problem , i appreaciate your help againe :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing bracket here

```
username: ['', Validators.required , Validators.email  , this.validateEmailNotTaken.bind(this)]
```

should be

```
username: ['', [Validators.required , Validators.email  , this.validateEmailNotTaken.bind(this)]]
```

Comment: I dont get any error now , the Validators.required, Validators.email are working, but this.validateEmailNotTaken.bind(this) seems not to work as it doesnt tell me that username is already in use . i've already tested the rest controller with ARC client and it works well .